# Array Object to string conversion using PHP( Laravel )

Tags: php, laravel

I have code like this in my Laravel project, and i want to return as single array.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "value 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "value 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "value 3"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "value 4"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "value 5"
    }
]
```

and i want to get like this

```
$output = "value 1,value 2,value 3,value 4,value 5";
```

Comment: It might help to show what you've tried and describe what goes wrong. Otherwise, it may appear that no research effort has been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel collection reduce method to get the string output

```php
$output = rtrim(
    collect($data)->reduce(fn($carry, $item) => $carry . "{$item['name']},"), ','
);
```

OR

```php
$output = implode(',', collect($data)->map(fn($item) => $item['name'])->all());
```

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy with Collection methods:

```
collect($array)->pluck('name')->join(',')
```

Or with array methods:

```
join(',', array_column($array, 'name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [];

foreach ($values as $value){
  $array[] = $value['name'];
}
```

this will return a single array but if you want it as a string (like your example) you need to do  like this:

$string = implode(',', $array);

Comment: `$value.name` is not PHP syntax.